# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>

Tags: django, anaconda, conda

I'm setting up the virtual environment of Django for the first time. I've downloaded the Anaconda library of Python in my D drive. So initially I set up the path of Python and Conda(Scripts) manually in advance system settings. But now when I'm creating the environment using command

`conda create --name mydjang0 django`

the command prompt is showing an error like this-

> C:\Users\AABHA GAUTAM> `conda create --name mydjang0 django`
> Solving environment: failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
> Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
> HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>
> If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
> a support request with your network engineering team.
>
> SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/pro/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))

Comment: Can you navigate to https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 in a browser?

Comment: Yes I can. this is what it looks like-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conda update CondaHTTPError: HTTP None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563757/conda-update-condahttperror-http-none)

Answer (score 4):

If you already have a .condarc file in your root folder. Then update the file by running this command.

`conda config --set ssl_verify false`

If you do not have a .condarc file, then create one and then run the above command. I have added both the commands below.

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using command prompt use Anaconda Prompt as administator.
run the same command there.

I also faced same issue with command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Only delete file .condrac from c:\users\user

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).