# conda install in Julia fails because of SSL on windows 10

Tags: ssl, julia, conda

`conda install xxx` fails with the following error:

> SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\',
>   \'tls_process_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify
>   failed\')])")))'))

Maybe there must be something very subtle causing the trouble in my environment but I really have no idea.

It used to work but after I reinstall Windows 10 image, the issue began to appear.
It is on Windows 10. Conda version is 4.7.12. My .condarc is placed in %USERPROFILE% and looks like:

```
channels:
  - defaults


show_channel_urls: true
allow_other_channels: true


proxy_servers:
  https: https://x.x.x.x:8080

ssl_verify: false
```

All available advice over the Internet for the above error tell that ssl_verify set to false is enough.

Where else should I take a look into?

EDIT:
I found some useful info at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56717433/7341479

It solves the issue for running conda install Anaconda Powershell opened in Admin. but it still remains for when I run pkg build PyCall in Julia