# Error creating new environment and conda install conda-clean

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, uninstallation, http-error

I keep getting an error whilst trying to make a new environment on anaconda. I also wanted to try to reinstall it from anaconda prompt and clear everything before reinstalling.

I've tried opening anaconda navigator as an administrator but still didn't work. I've also tried using anaconda prompt using 'conda install anaconda-clean' 
but I kept getting the same error for both

This is the error that I get:

```
(base) C:\Users\212749017>conda install pip
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/msys2/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023A45D7BC88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))"))
```

Comment: are you working behind a proxy ?

Comment: @prashantrana Yes I am using a laptop from work. I was able to download pandas and networkX fine previously. However, I now need graphviz and now cannot create a new environment for it

Comment: have you tried `conda create -n <env name>` to create virtual env, why install graphvz in new environment, you can install in old  envirnment where your wqhole code reside

Comment: you can use this [thread](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/2760) to solve your issue

Comment: @prashantrana 
(base) C:\Users\212749017>conda create -n graphviz
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

Comment: @prashantrana followed by CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -
An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

Comment: `conda create -n graphviz` this must mork, it will create a new python virtual environment and you dont need internet connection for this, after warning in termainla you will asked for creation, press y, new environment will be created. now go in environment by `conda activate grapghviz`  then install graphviz using `python -m pip install graphviz`

Comment: @prashantrana sorry, I've tried entering the conda create -n graphviz again but I kept getting the same error as above and so cannot move forward from it

Comment: i think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563757/conda-update-condahttperror-http-none this same issue as your , go through this it will help you

Comment: @prashantrana Could I please ask more on how to do the .condarc method? I don't really understand how they approach it. Sorry, I am new to using anaconda and have been trying to look into this problem for the whole day now

Comment: no need to find the file , just do `conda config --set ssl_verify no`

Comment: @prashantrana hi, so I've entered the conda config -- set ssl_verify no, and then did the conda create -n graphviz and I still keep getting the same error

Comment: this is strange , this thread https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/2760 got the people having same problems, you can go through this  to solve issue

Comment: @prashantrana I have read through the thread. However, I do not understand the .condarc method. Could I possibly ask as to how this is executed?

Comment: condarc is a file, where your config/setting related  to conda to follow when executing is stored. you can saw this file using `conda info` command in terminal