# Installing tensorflow 1.9 on raspberry pi*addressed by modifying code to work with tf 2

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, pip, raspberry-pi

**updated code to work with tensorflow 2.4 to get around issue**

I'm trying to install Tensorflow 1.9 on a Raspberry Pi as it is a requirement of the code I want to run. It installs fine on my Macbook using `pip install tensorflow==1.9.0`, but on the Pi I get the error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.9.0 (from versions: 0.11.0, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.13.1, 1.14.0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.9.0
```

I'm using a Conda (miniconda3) environment with Python 3.6.

Would using Ubuntu Desktop instead of Raspberry Pi OS work maybe? Or is there perhaps a way to build it from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.9?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install python version 3.6 or other compatible versions in conda. Tensorflow does not work on versions higher than 3.8 and has identified issues with some other versions. I recommend using python 3.6 through conda. You will also probably need to move the

- libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
- libssl-1_1-x64.dll
  files from anaconda3\Library\bin to anaconda3/DLLs. You can find more details about this issue if you run into it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563757/conda-update-condahttperror-http-none).

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Any advice on .dll files is invalid on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

To install Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi run:

```
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
```

and then

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

You can also compilte TensorflowLite and use if you wish. The compile TensorflowLite on RPi refer [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_rpi)

Comment: this installs tensorflow 1.14 which isn't the version I needed, but I went with 2.4.0 in the end, easier to adjust for compatibilty

Comment: Oh ok, no probs. Sorry if caused any problems. But there was no problem with this fundamentally right?