# How to solve "CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED" error in WSL?

Tags: python, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, miniconda

I have enabled WSL in my Windows 10 and installed Ubuntu **20.04 LTS** from Microsoft store.

To use meep software, I am following the [installation process](https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation/#conda-packages) on my Windows 10. Unfortunately, when I am running below command,

```
conda create -n mp -c conda-forge pymeep
```

I am getting an error like,

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64'
```

I have tried to disable ssl with below command,

```
conda config --set ssl_verify no
```

But no luck. Now, **How to resolve this issue?**

here is the --verbose output of the command,

```
tasmia@TASMIA-PC:~/study/softwares$ conda create -n mp -c conda-forge pymeep -v
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46d7220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46d7be0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /conda-forge/linux-64/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46d74c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /conda-forge/noarch/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46d7fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/r/linux-64/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46ef7c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46fd4f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/main/linux-64/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46ef3d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46ef550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /conda-forge/linux-64/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46efb20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/r/linux-64/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46ef970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /conda-forge/noarch/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46efd00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46fd6d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/main/linux-64/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46fda30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46fdc10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /conda-forge/linux-64/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46fdd90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/r/linux-64/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e46fdf10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /conda-forge/noarch/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e464c0d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e464c250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /pkgs/main/linux-64/current_repodata.json

failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e464c700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/linux-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e464c700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 701, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
    resp = session.get(join_url(url, filename), headers=headers, proxies=session.proxies,
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/linux-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f02e464c700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 41, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'create')
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 261, in install
    unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
    unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
    ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 425, in _collect_all_metadata
    index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 1020, in _prepare
    reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 288, in get_reduced_index
    new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 140, in query_all
    result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 608, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 445, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 132, in <lambda>
    subdir_query = lambda url: tuple(SubdirData(Channel(url), repodata_fn=repodata_fn).query(
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 145, in query
    self.load()
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 210, in load
    _internal_state = self._load()
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 375, in _load
    raw_repodata_str = fetch_repodata_remote_request(
  File "/home/tasmia/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 806, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
    raise CondaHTTPError(help_message,
conda.exceptions.CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Miniconda on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) fails with CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67923183/miniconda-on-wsl2-ubuntu-20-04-fails-with-condahttperror-http-000-connection)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this discussion here helps:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9948

In summary three fixes are suggested there:

1. Install an older version (4.7.12) of conda / miniconda [see here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9948#issuecomment-637415912)
2. Change file- & directory-permissions of your miniconda-installation (`chmod -R 777 ~/.miniconda3`) [see here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9948#issuecomment-906410470)
3. Restart wsl (`wsl --shutdown`) [see here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9948#issuecomment-906410470)

Comment: Restarting WSL worked for me. I just wish I knew why.

Comment: Changing permissions worked for me: `chmod -R 777 ~/.miniconda3`. I'm using linux (WSL) on windows 10.

Comment: Step 2 and 3 worked for me without downgrading

Answer (score 1):

I got those Conda HTTP errors on my Windows 11 Home preview and couldn't find the problem so I tried it on my Windows 11 Pro computer and it worked fine.

Comment: I filed a complaint on the Windows Insider Feedback Hub.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in Windows 10 by enabling "automatically detect settings" under the proxy settings panel

Comment: Unfortunately, I does not work for me.