# Which anaconda version comes with python 3.7 as default?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to use python3.7.13 with anaconda.

From conda [documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html)

`conda install python=3.7.13` should do the job however since all this is taking place at my corporation which is blocked with firewall I get following error:

`An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors are ofrten intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way. ProxyError(....`

I've re-tried multiple times but no luck. After some googling I found that there is a workaround -> from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563757/conda-update-condahttperror-http-none)

But it increase risk of attack which I cannot afford.

So I am trying to find out version of Anaconda that comes with python 3.7.13 therefore I could ask my service team to download Anaconda for me.

Comment: Once installed Conda let's you create an instance of whatever version of Python you like, e.g. `conda create -n my_env_name python=3.7.13`. So just ask for the most recent version

Comment: @MattClarke Since current default python version is 3.6.4, I've tried `conda create -n test_env python=3.5` however this getting `ProxyError`

Comment: You might need to update your conda version. Have you run conda update conda?

Comment: If you search for conda cheat sheet there is a PDF which is a useful reference